# How can I enable Uniflex BSD sockets to be BROADCAST?

Tags: sockets, bsd, retro-computing

I am restoring a Tektronix 4404 running Uniflex from 1986. The BSD socket implementation is done by Network Research Corporation; there are no docs.  I have header files but there are no function declarations…

I am looking for any information around functions such as:

`net_ioctl()` which looks like the way you control sockets for this OS.

Frustratingly, `setsockopt()` does actually support `SO_REUSEADDR` but `SO_BROADCAST` is not defined.

I've run strings to get entrypoints etc and the headers contain lots of internal socket implementation structs which feels like you're meant to walk those internal structures to effect what you need.

To give you a flavour, net/netioc.h looks like this.  Functions such as _el_init() feel like some kind of entrypoint, but I'm pretty lost..

```
/*  Copyright (C) 3/10/86 by Network Research Corporation
 *  All rights reserved.  No part of this software may be disclosed or distributed in any form or by any means without the prior written consent of Network Research Corporation.
 */
/*  Module: h       File: /nrc/rel/h/s.netioc.h  */
/*  Version 11.2 as of 86/03/10 at 10:31:12  */

#ifndef _NETIOC_
#define _NETIOC_

#ifndef _STD_
#include <net/std.h>
#endif

#define EL_VERSION  0
#define EL_MAX_SIZE 10

#ifndef SOIOCBASE
#define SOIOCBASE   ('s' << 8)
#endif

#ifndef SOIOCGNTTY
#define SOIOCGNTTY  (SOIOCBASE-2)
#define SOIOCSNTTY  (SOIOCBASE-1)
#endif

#ifndef SOIOCATMARK
#define SOIOCATMARK (SOIOCBASE-3)   /* for MSG_OOB */
#endif

#ifndef ENIOCBASE
#define ENIOCBASE   ('e' << 8)
#endif

#ifndef INPIOCBASE
#define INPIOCBASE  ('i' << 8)
#endif

#define INPIOCDOWNLOAD      (INPIOCBASE + 0)
#define INPIOCEXECUTE       (INPIOCBASE + 1)
#define INPIOCINITIALIZE    (INPIOCBASE + 2)
#define INPIOCPROBE     (INPIOCBASE + 3)
#define INPIOCDIDDLE        (INPIOCBASE + 4)

/* Values for raw ethernet ioctls.  These select the action inside
 * the link layer ioctl routine.
 */
#define ENIOCEND    (ENIOCBASE+10)
#define ENIOCNORMAL ENIOCBASE   /* accept broadcast and specific */
#define ENIOCPROMISC    (ENIOCBASE+1)   /* accept all undamaged packets */
#define ENIOCALL    (ENIOCBASE+2)   /* accept ALL packets */
#define ENIOCRESET  (ENIOCBASE+3)

#ifdef  MSDOS
/* Raw socket driver interface ioctls for MSDOS only! */
#define SDIOCBASE   ('o' << 8)

#define SDIOCSTK    SDIOCBASE   /* give pre-sockdrv stack */
#endif  MSDOS

/* Defined values for el.el_u2.i field of el array header */
#define ELC_ACCEPT  0   /* accept a new connection */
#define ELC_ADDR    1   /* give back the current net address */
#define ELC_ASYNC   2   /* set/reset the socket as async */
#define ELC_ATTACH  3   /* attach to a protocol */
#define ELC_BETIMER 4   /* assume the timeout chores */
#define ELC_BIND    5   /* bind to a network address */
#define ELC_BLOCKING    6   /* turn off/on blocking */
#define ELC_CONNECT 7   /* actively seek connection */
#define ELC_DEBUG   8   /* network debugging entrypoint */
#define ELC_DIDDLE  9   /* peek/poke kernel variables */
#define ELC_EBDEV   10  /* external block device attach */
#define ELC_GETOPT  11  /* get protocol options now current */
#define ELC_INDEX   12  /* give/get the socket index */
#define ELC_LISTEN  13  /* listen for connection requests */
#define ELC_NEXTSOCKET  14  /* give me the next available socket index */
#define ELC_PAIR    15  /* activate the socketpair() code */
#define ELC_PEERADDR    16  /* deliver up the peer address */
#define ELC_RECV    17  /* recv a packet */
#define ELC_SEND    18  /* send a packet */
#define ELC_SETOPT  19  /* set protocol specific options */
#define ELC_SHUTDOWN    20  /* disallow read/write on socket */
#define ELC_SREAD   21  /* read data (used in VMS) */
#define ELC_SWRITE  22  /* write data (used in VMS) */
#define ELC_NSELECT 23  /* select available io on multiple sockets */
#define ELC_PIOCTL  24  /* protocol specific ioctl */
#define ELC_REJECT  25  /* reject a connection request */

#define EL_HEADER   (0x4000 | EL_VERSION)
#define EL_NOOP     0
#define EL_PROTOCOL 1   /* as in XNS_DGRAM */
#define EL_FAMILY   2   /* as in XNS, DARPA etc */
#define EL_INDEX    3   /* request/give a socket index */
#define EL_A_LEN    4   /* where to place the address length */
#define EL_D_LEN    5   /* where to place the data length */
#define EL_DATA     6   /* where's the beef? */
#define EL_DEST     7   /* destination network address */
#define EL_SRC      8   /* src network address */
#define EL_FLAGS    9   /* as in MSG_OOB MSG_PEEK etc. */
#define EL_TYPE     10  /* type field, interpreted by protocol */
#define EL_P0       11  /* protocol specific param 0 */
#define EL_P1       12  /* protocol specific param 1 */
#define EL_P2       13  /* protocol specific param 2 */
#define EL_P3       14  /* protocol specific param 3 */
#define EL_P4       15  /* protocol specific param 4 */
#define EL_PHDR     16  /* protocol header */
#define EL_PHLEN    17  /* protocol header length */

/* Flags for el.el_flags, musn't overlap common flag area (see <flags.h>) */
#define F_EL_STRUCTURED 0x1 /* structured data (32 bits) */
#define F_EL_IN     0x2 /* incoming (user ==> kernel) data element */
#define F_EL_OUT    0x4 /* outgoing (kernel ==> user) data element */
#define F_EL_KERNEL 0x8 /* element is in kernel space */
#define F_EL_ALLOC  0x10    /* element is in heap space -- must be freed */
#define F_EL_PROCESS    0x20    /* some additional processing to do */
#define F_EL_PPROCESS   0x40    /* don't free, more processing to do */
#define F_EL_MPRE_ALLOC 0x80    /* m structure is pre-allocate */

#define F_EL_KRESERVED  F_EL_KERNEL /* el flags reserved for kernel use */

/* if the size of el changes fix el_cnt()!! */
typedef struct el {
    u16 el_type;
    u16 el_flags;
    u32 el_len;
    u32 el_u1;
    u32 el_u2;
} el;

import  el  * _elc(), * _el_init();

/* How many used. Expects size of an el to be 32 bytes */
#define el_cnt(elp1)    (((int)((char *)elp1[0].el_u1 - (char *)(elp1))) >> 4)

/* the next one available */
#define el_end(elp1)    ((el *)(elp1)->el_u1)

/* the last valid one */
#define el_last(elp1)   (((el *)elp1->el_u1) - 1)

/* size in bytes*/
#define el_size(elp1)   (int)((char *)(elp1)[0].el_u1 - (char *)(elp1))

#define el_ioc(elp) ((SOIOCBASE-1)+el_cnt(elp))
#define el_u(elp, type, u1) \
    _elc(elp, type, (u32)sizeof(u32), (u16)F_EL_STRUCTURED)->el_u1 = (u32)(u1)

#ifdef  KERNEL

#define el_init(elp, cmnd, flags) \
    _el_init(elp,(u32)(cmnd),(u16)flags| F_EL_KERNEL)
#ifndef kcanonptr
#define kcanonptr(p)    ((u32)p)
#endif
#define el_ucp(elp, type, p, size, f) \
    _elc(elp, type, (u32)(size), (u16)(f))->el_u1=((u32)p)
#define el_cp(elp, type, p, size, f) \
    _elc(elp, type, (u32)(size), (u16)(f)|(u16)F_EL_KERNEL)->el_u1=(kcanonptr(p))
#define el_up(elp, type, p, f) \
    _elc(elp, type, (u32)sizeof(u32), (u16)(f)|(u16)(F_EL_STRUCTURED|F_EL_KERNEL))->el_u1=(kcanonptr(p))
#define el_xin(elp,kdest,c) ((elp[0].el_len==c)?el_in(elp,kdest,c):EINVAL)
#define el_xout(elp,udest,c)    ((elp[0].el_len==c)?el_out(elp,udest,c):EINVAL)
#else   KERNEL
#define el_init(elp, cmnd, flags)   _el_init(elp, (u32)(cmnd), (u16)flags)
#ifndef canonptr
#define canonptr(p) ((u32)p)
#endif
#define el_cp(elp, type, p, size, f) \
    _elc(elp, type, (u32)(size), (u16)(f))->el_u1=(canonptr(p))
#define el_up(elp, type, p, f) \
    _elc(elp, type, (u32)sizeof(u32), (u16)(f)|(u16)F_EL_STRUCTURED)->el_u1=(canonptr(p))
#endif  KERNEL

#endif  _NETIOC_

/*
 *  @(#)netioc.h    11.2 (NRC)
 */
```

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on the [TekScopes group](https://groups.io/g/TekScopes/topics). Probably no-one there will know the answer directly but you will get all kinds of redirection to other resources. Very knowledgeable guys including some Tek employees and the Tek Museum.

Comment: Cheers.  If you think of other places, please reach out!